# How to resolve graphene django node field with Many-to-Many relationship

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python

I get "Received incompatible instance error" when i try to resolve node field with many-to-many relationship. I need help to resolve this issue. I have listed down the models, graphql types in graphene django for reference.

Code Version that i use:
graphene django version: 2.2.0
python verions: 3.5.2
django version: (2, 0, 8, 'final', 0)

```
models.py
---------
class ModelA:
    name
    description

Class ModelB:
    model_code
    description
    field3
    field4
    model_links = models.ManyToManyField(ModelA, through='ModelAModelB')

class ModelAModelB:
    model_a = models.ForeignKey('ModelA', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=False)
    model_b = models.ForeignKey('ModelB', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=False)

    class Meta:
        #index is defined here


Graphene Django:


Type Definition
---------------
class ModelANode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node, )

class ModelBNode(DjangoObjectType):
    modellinks = graphene.Field(ModelANode)

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node, )

    def resolve_modellinks(self, info, **args):
        #how do i resolve this field

        #I tried the below code
        modelB = ModelB.objects.get(id=self.id)
        modelaIDs = modelB.modelamodelb_set.select_related('model_a').values_list('model_a_id', flat=True)
        modelARecs = ModelA.objects.filter(id__in=modelaIDs)

        return [graphene.relay.Node.get_node_from_global_id(
                'ModelANode', 
                info,
                to_global_id('ModelANode', rec.id) 
            ) for rec in modelARecs]

Graphql Call:
------------
allmodelBs {
    model_code
    description
    field3
    field4
    modellinks {
        id
    }
}
```

I get the data for Model B fields but the below error is displayed for modellinks:

```
"errors": [
    {
        "message": "Received incompatible instance \"[None, None]\"."
    },
    {
        "message": "Received incompatible instance \"[]\"."
    }
]
```

I need help to resolve many-to-many relationships Node Field.

Answer (score 1):

As there in no context of usage, I will mention the following.

`DjangoObjectType` has a nice feature - you could use pure django model instance instead of it and:

1. It will be converted to graphql type as resolution ends
2. `self` in your `resolve_*` methods will be the actual django model

So you could use it:

```
modelARecs = [rel.model_a for rel in self.modelamodelb_set.all()]
```

Instead of:

```
modelB = ModelB.objects.get(id=self.id)
modelaIDs = modelB.modelamodelb_set.select_related('model_a').values_list('model_a_id', flat=True)
modelARecs = ModelA.objects.filter(id__in=modelaIDs)
```

And just return `modelARecs` as it is django model `DjangoObjectType` is declared for.

Comment: The context is this. Model A and B has a MTM rel with pivot table AB. Model B has a reference to list of A records, so i was trying to get list of model A's records for matching B records.  I did replace the code as per your recommendation but still i receive incompatible instance error with Model Name and value displayed.

Comment: I did find a solution which is just do not add a reference field to Model A in Model B Node i.e remove modellinks in the above example. While querying model B Node you will be able to automatically get records of Model A using model_links as it is already referenced in Model A.